# Microsoft Edge browser history bug on input type radio and checkbox?

Tags: html, microsoft-edge

Microsoft Edge remembers the selected option of the select box but not which radio button I selected and which checkboxes I checked. All other browsers remember all settings.

edge1.html:

```
<form action="edge2.html">
 <select name="S">
  <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="B">B</option>
  <option value="C">C</option>
 <select><br>

 <input type="radio" name="XV" value="1"><br>
 <input type="radio" name="XV" value="2"><br>
 <input type="radio" name="XV" value="3"><br>

 <input type="checkbox" name="C1" value="C1"><br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="C2" value="C2"><br>

 <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

edge2.html can be empty.

How can I tell the Microsoft Edge browser to remember the selected radio buttons and checkboxes and preselect them when I go back to this page?

Answer (score 0):

Found an awnser on a microsoft form which says it is not supported at the moment

> Hello Chris Rebert,
>
> We sincerely appreciate your taking time to provide your feedback. Radio button and checkbox are not supported input types for oninput event on MS Edge.
>   Please see the following list for supported input types.
>
> input type=" text, textarea, password, date, datetime, email, month, number, range, search, tel, time, url, week, color"
>
> Additionally, you can file your suggestion at the uservoice site so others can review your suggestion and vote it up! 
>   https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/257854-internet-explorer-platform.
>
> Best Regards,
>   The Microsoft Edge Team

Another:
https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/1883692

There's a feedback item to support this feature which has over 100 votes at the moment:
https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/257854-microsoft-edge-developer/suggestions/10182111--input-type-checkbox-type-radio-should-fire-in